# Flatten out a list in java

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I was asked this question in an interview

> Given a hypothetical list in java that, along with holding integer
>   content, may also hold another list of similar type

Example: `[1,3,5,[6,7],8,9,10,[11,13,15,[16,17,[18,19]]],20]`

Output should be:

```
[1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Easy I thought! So i came with a recursive solution that solved the problem! Or not?

The interviewer said sublists could go down to any depths and hence may result in stackoverflow error!

I tried coming up with a non recursive solution, but couldn't. Could anyone tell what that **non recursive solution** might be?

Comment: How is this list stored?

Comment: Good question, and I think to answer the problem as is we will need make our own assumptions about what this data structure will look like.

Comment: With recursive code you always have the possibility of a stack overflow if the recursion goes too deep, but this is really only a theoretical possibility in this case - you have to have a *very* deeply nested list (thousands of levels?) before you'd get a SOE in practice.

Comment: @PM77-1 well, it's an *hypothetical list in java*. I'm not sure how it may be stored, probably a `List<Object>` and using `typeof` to check if the proper type is `Integer` or `List<Object>` (again).

Comment: *sublists could go down to any depths and hence may result in stackoverflow error!* well, increase the size of the stack and call it a day. And seriously, that should not happen unless you have some nasty data.

Comment: Actually, recursion is a very clean way to solve your problem.

Comment: Hm, isn't that a composite pattern too? So maybe a composite iterator? Which ideed will be a recursive solution but with iterators.

Comment: Can we pretend that we do not know that `toString()` for lists is internally recursive?  So we will get a string and remove internal square brackets.

Comment: Even though we implement it iteratively we will have to use a stack which again might result in SOE.

Comment: @Ouney you seem to be confused of having two terms stack.  One is a data structure used by the program and it is allocated on the heap.  The other is the stack of the program and recursive calls create separate frames on it.  A stackoverflow happens when you exceed the size of the second stack.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - Not really, I understand this point :)

Comment: Peps can it be that the interviewer meant that your recursive solution woukd result in SoF not *any* recursive solution. It is easy to make a mistake and store too many things on the stack

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev no he specifically said that my solution is recursive which often result in so errors, hence i should give him a non recursive solution!

Comment: @Ouney using a stack in the iterative approach can not cause stack overflow.  It may overflow the heap but not the stack

Comment: @PM77-1 i should have asked the interviewer these questions, but guess i was too nervous to do that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use LinkedList as a stack.

```
public static List<Object> flattenNonRecursive(List<Object> list) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedList<Object> stack = new LinkedList<>(list);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Object e = stack.pop();
        if (e instanceof List<?>)
            stack.addAll(0, (List<?>)e);
        else
            result.add(e);
    }
    return result;
}

public static List<Object> list(Object... args) {
    return Arrays.asList(args);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> list = list(1, 3, 5, list(6, 7), 8, 9, 10, list(11, 13, 15, list(16, 17, list(18, 19))), 20);
    System.out.println("flatten=" + flattenNonRecursive(list));
}
```

result

```
flatten=[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. A pedantic note: the LinkedList is being used as a *stack*, not a queue. Also check out [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) which provides *push* and *pop* methods and usually outperforms the Stack and LinkedList classes when used like this.

Comment: nice solution, it is!

Comment: @dnault I see what you are saying but it might be a bit cumbersome adding the contents of a list to the '0th' index of the ArrayDeque

Answer (score 4):

Here's an iterative Java implementation (partially based on sarvesh's answer):

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] ars) {
        List<Object> list = asList(asList(1, 2), 3, 4, asList(5, asList(6, 7)));

        System.out.println(flatten(list));
    }

    public static List<Integer> flatten(Iterable<Object> list) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Deque<Iterator> deque = new ArrayDeque<Iterator>();
        deque.add(list.iterator());

        while (!deque.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator it = deque.pop();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Object obj = it.next();
                if (obj instanceof Iterable) {
                    deque.push(it);
                    it = ((Iterable) obj).iterator();
                } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                    result.add((Integer) obj);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use DFS(Depth First Search) procedure for each element in the list. Below is sample code from wiki

```
1  procedure DFS-iterative(G,v):
2      let S be a stack
3      S.push(v)
4      while S is not empty
5            v = S.pop() 
6            if v is not labeled as discovered:
7                label v as discovered
8                for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
9                    S.push(w)
```

Comment: Isn't a typical dfs solution always recursive too? And a non recursive version of dfs awaits a binary tree?

Comment: It looks like, but it can be written non-recursively, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: A dfs can be non recursive and a dfs(like any search) will form a tree but it will rarely be binary

Answer (score 0):

You could use below kind of algorithm

```
    public List<?> flatten(List<?> source) {
        List<?> currentSource = source;
        List<Object> flattenedList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        boolean loop = true;
        while (loop) {
            loop = false;
            for (Object item : currentSource) {
                if (item instanceof Collection<?>) {
                    flattenedList.addAll((Collection<?>) item);
                    loop = true;
                } else {
                    flattenedList.add(item);
                }
            }
            if (loop) {
                currentSource = flattenedList;
                flattenedList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            }
        }

        return flattenedList;
    }
```